# On Facebook Page Tab ASP file suffix .asp doesn't work

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

FBML Error (line 2): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

how to solve???

Answer (score 2):

According to [google](https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=illegal%20tag%20%22body%22%20under%20%22fb:tab-position%22%20asp&oq=illegal%20tag%20%22body%22%20under%20%22fb:tab-position%22%20asp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3098l3889l1l4145l4l4l0l0l0l0l116l387l2.2l4l0&gs_l=hp.3...3098l3889l1l4145l4l4l0l0l0l0l116l387l2j2l4l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=988d2a8b933cd005&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1600&bih=802), this is because IIS doesn't allow POST requests html files. So check if you have spacial hooks for post requests.

Also, [FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) will be deprecated in June this year, so you might want to ditch it alltogether.

There's also another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472134/im-getting-this-error-on-my-facebook-app-tab-illegal-tag-body-under-fbtab), detailing the same issue, which might help you.